# Authorization of HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I am trying to get some data from a Wep API using ASP MVC. 
I made a new controller and added the required namespace.
But for some reason I keep getting error 401 - Unauthorized. What am I missing?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<LanguageModel> LangInfo = new List<LanguageModel>();
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(Utilities.Utility.Username(), Utilities.Utility.Password());
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(Utilities.Utility.Username(), Utilities.Utility.Password());
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("/api1/....removed sensitive link");

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var LangResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                    LangInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LanguageModel>>(LangResponse);

                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return View(LangInfo);
            }
        }
```

For some reason it is not giving the handler? Kinda new to this, sorry in advance :)

return from Res:

```
+       Res {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Set-Cookie: syracuse.sid.8124=60f4b5c6-4a14-47bb-94fd-fff9ea670bdf; path=/;HttpOnly;
  Set-Cookie: client.id=cdaf1589-38bf-47db-a3e6-0a9fb742190b; path=/; expires=Sun, 07 Oct 2018 21:12:58 GMT;HttpOnly;
  WWW-Authenticate: Redirect /auth/login/page
  x-frame-options: DENY
  x-content-type-options: nosniff
  x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
  content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self';
  cache-control: no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0, s-maxage=0, private
  pragma: no-cache
  Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2018 21:12:58 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/json
  content-language: en-US
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```

Comment: I have used basic auth in Postman without problems @mjwills

Comment: For basic auth I use this: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{LoginName}:{Password}")));`

Comment: @Gusman Tried that before. Returned the same Authorization error. Also, Could you explain me the difference?  ;)

Comment: You are using the `HttpClient` wrong and it's destabilizing your software. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: You are adding "UserName" as the scheme and "Password" as the content, that will produce a header like this: `Authorization: (username) (password)` which is incorrect for basic authorization, basic authorization must look like this: `Authorization: (schema) (data)` something like this at the end: `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be mistaken, but you first declare some headers.

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(Utilities.Utility.Username(), Utilities.Utility.Password());
```

but a few lines later you clear them:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
```

I am no expert in HttpClient, but this doesn't make sense.